# Which way of writing this sum of attribute values is better?

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

I want to sum two attributes of a descendant element. This XPath expression accomplishes what I want:

```
sum(a/b/@x) + sum(a/b/@y)
```

...But it seems inefficient to invoke the computation of the `a/b` path expression twice. It feels even more awkward if I were to need to sum three or more of these attributes.

My thoughts have led to this:

```
sum(a/b/@*[name() = ('x','y')])
```

Is there a smarter way to write this expression?

Comment: Micro-optimisations like this are unlikely to make any measurable difference to performance - since XPath is side-effect-free the processor is at liberty to optimize these kinds of things by, for example, cacheing the results of intermediate path expressions.

Comment: Thank you. I completely agree with the premise of avoiding micro-optimization traps. I had suspected—for precisely the reason you raised— that the subexpression was cached anyway. However, the ways I had envisioned writing this expression seemed inelegant: the first one because of the repetition within the expression; and the second because of its obvious complexity. @MartinHonnen's answer is what I was hoping for.

Comment: Yes, Martin's approach is more elegant, and better for maintainability particularly if the repeated expression is more complex than a simple `a/b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sum(a/b/(@x, @y))`.

Comment: Note that these various expressions are not equivalent in the case where @x or @y attributes are absent (which means that optimizers don't have complete freedom to replace one with another).

Comment: @MichaelKay, I've failed at coming up with a test where the values of these three expressions are not identical for all the interesting input documents I can come up with (missing @x, missing @y, missing (@x,@y)). Do you perhaps mean that the expressions *if I were to omit the sum() function* are not equivalent?

Comment: Perhaps I was reading one of them as `sum(/a/b/(@x+@y))` which would give NaN if one of the attributes is absent.